# Manejo de fechas en JavaScript con librería highchrats

Tags: javascript, mysql, highcharts

Tengo un problema en librería de `highchrats` llamo el campo fecha de `mysql` y lo transformo para que sea mostrado en gráfico pero en `highchart`usando el comando `Date.UTC` de `JavaScript`

```
[Date.UTC(2016, 06, 6), 14];
```

Como 6 de Julio, cuando debería ser el 6 de Junio

¿Alguna forma de corregirlo?

Comment: intenta con esto `[new Date('2016-06-06').getTime() ,14]` deberia funcionar si es asi agrego la respuesta @Francisco

Comment: Podrías utilizar https://momentjs.com/ para manejar las fechas, es una excelente opción!

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque en javascript los meses son "zero-based", que quiere decir que empiezan en 0, por lo tanto Enero será 0, Febrero 1.... por lo tanto Julio correspondería a la posición 6 del array.

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!!

EDIT: Función que convierte un datetime en MySQL a JS Date():

```
     function mysqlTimeStampToDate(timestamp) {
    //function parses mysql datetime string and returns javascript Date object
    //input has to be in this format: 2007-06-05 15:26:02
    var regex=/^([0-9]{2,4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9]) (?:([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/;
    var parts=timestamp.replace(regex,"$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6").split(' ');
    return new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2],parts[3],parts[4],parts[5]);
  }
```

Comment: Eso lo se , pero como cambio la fecha que obtengo de una columna de la base de datos mysql para que el 2016,06,6 sea junio y no julio como se muestra

Comment: He editado la respuesta con una función que convierte un datetime a Date() de js, dime si te sirvió, y sinó explícame el error y mañana lo miro por la mañana. Saludos!